# Can you create a HTML list that cuts into a DIV containing a gradient?

Tags: html, css

I know it's possible to crop shapes through CSS onto background images but that's not exactly what I'm after as I want to crop a list to a div.

I want this kind of effect:

[image]

I'm currently using PHP in Wordpress to create a custom post type, and I am creating dedicated web-pages for each category (9 in total). I have put together a 'table of contents' on the left which will display the title of each article within the category, which would act as an anchor link to the correct article down below, on the same page.

I understand that there are options via CSS nth:children pseudonyms but I really don't see how this could work as the table of contents would differ in length depending on the subjects, and are likely to change in the future.

I have thought about doing the following:

```
<div class="gradient">
    <ul class="gradient-list">
        <li><?php code ?></li>
        <li><?php code ?></li>
        <li><?php code ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.gradient {
background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}

.gradient-list {
  padding: 10px;
  }

.gradient-list li {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      clip-path: rectangle(0px 5px, 10px 4px);
}
```

But naturally, this won't work. Finally, in my sketch, I have made the list items change from white to black when it reached a certain contrast. If this isn't easy or even possible, I will just use brighter colours for the background of my list so this is less important to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a `clip-path` trick and pseudo element like below:

```css
.gradient-list {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative; /* make the pseudo element relative to the same element so they overlap */
  z-index: 0;
}

.gradient-list li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  clip-path: inset(0); /* make the pseudo element cover only the li area */
}

/* below your gradient */
.gradient-list li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="gradient-list">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="gradient-list">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
  <li>List 6</li>
</ul>
```